# Cannot extract data from post request in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, get, axios, put

I am sending a post request using axios in react to a nodejs backend and mysql database.

At the server side when I log req.body, it is undefined
and this is the params and query part when I log the request on server side:

```
params: {},
query: {},
```

This is inside the handlelogin method in react:

```
 handleLogin=(event)=>
    {event.preventDefault();
        let formfields={...this.state.formfields};
        axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/login',{formfields
        })
        .then(res=>
            {
                    console.log("response receieved");  
                })
        .catch(err=>
        {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

This is the node script( inside routes):

```
const express = require('express');
const exp = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
exp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
exp.use(bodyParser.json());
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/api/login',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('Inside login-serverside');
    console.log(req);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to submit forms and pdf files(later) but I cannot access them on the server side.I can acces request.parameters when I make a get request.What is the issue here?

What are body,params and query used for, respectively and what is the difference?

Comment: Hey Abdul, the first thing you need to set  `body.urlencode` value true. I refer this project [React with express API](https://github.com/esausilva/example-create-react-app-express)

Comment: Right now urlenconded:false works, but could you tell me when should it be set to true.

Comment: If extended is false, you can not post "nested object".
`person[name] = 'cw'
// Nested Object = { person: { name: cw } }`
If extended is true, you can do whatever way that you like.

Comment: OK great! Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me why do I need to import body parser in my server.js file, even after having imported it in my login file as in the node script in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I had not included body parser in my main server.js file

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
exp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
```

After including this, it's working. I can now successfully use request.body and access the parameters passed in axios.post .

Though I am still confused about the use of params,query,data and body respectively.

Comment: You still need help about it?

Comment: No thanks but I'd like to know why it is necessary to import that in my server.js file when I use router and import the necessary dependencies in the login file.